# Validating the length of a form input value in Angular Dart

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

How can I specify that a form input only consider values of a minimum and maximum length as valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this change](https://github.com/matsko/angular.dart/commit/ec34a33c98b664d7a5ae4263c63bc29d73259072#diff-88dba07db9ecd68ba9a2e5de11fe2282) in the Angular GitHub repository contains a `NgModelMaxLengthValidator` which looks suspiciouly what you are looking for (checked in 8 days ago)
Maybe it's not yet released because I couldn't find it in my Angular package directory